# Kubernetes Nginx Controller Regex Rules Are Not Working

Tags: linux, regex, http, nginx, kubernetes

I am recently trying to build an Nginx Ingress network for my Kubernetes cluster. I am using Kubernetes 1.15.0 and Nginx 1.17.2 by the ingress controller image docker.io/nginx/nginx-ingress:alpine.

I am testing using a simple server which just tells the client what the requested path is. This is to learn about rewrite targets and path rules in the Ingress resource configuration. Below is the ingress config file I am using,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes-brion-us
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 1000
        path: "/test"
      - backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 1000
        path: "/abc/(.*)"
```

Below is the output of atempting to access those services,

```
> curl http://kubernetes-brion-us/test
incoming url /test
> curl http://kubernetes-brion-us/abc/test
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.2</center>
</body>
</html>
> curl "http://kubernetes-brion-us/abc/(.*)"
incoming url /abc/(.*)
```

Within the controller pods, the Nginx configuration reflects the behavior above,

```
/ # grep location /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-ingress-test.conf 
    location /test {
    location /abc/(.*) {
/ # grep root /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-ingress-test.conf 
/ #
```

According to Kubernetes documentation, the ingress.spec.rules.http.paths.path resource "is an extended POSIX regex matched against the path of an incoming request."

Besides the Nginx configuration files not using the "location ~ /abc/(.*)" syntax for regex rules that I suspected, there are no "root" rewrite targets for the location directives. My simple server indicates this as well.

I used [nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md) to install the Nginx ingress controllers.

**Answers for the following questions would be appreciated**

- Are my nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io annotations not being applied? If so, why?
- Why are the Nginx controllers not adhering to the regex rules I have supplied?
- Have I downloaded the wrong nginx-ingress image? If so, which should I have downloaded?
- Is this the right place to ask or should I move this to a github issue for the nginx-ingress project?

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong image and installation process from nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress. I needed to use this one instead https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx.